# Building a Klipfolio klip. How do I count all child nodes in a JSON stream?

Tags: json, xpath, klipfolio

I wish to count members that has status='active' the JSON stream. This will equal the sum of our members.

I'm able to select all members by `@/name`, but I'm not able to filter on only those who are active.

According to [Klipfolios documentation](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547118-About-JSON-and-XML-data-sources), it should be possible to count single elements:[image]

```
[
    {
        "_id": "58aabc92e846502357fc0f69",
        "email": "mail@me.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "office": "1122",
        "phone": "555-555",
        "status": "active",
    },
    {
        "_id": "58aabc92e846502357fc0f69",
        "email": "mail@me.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "office": "1122",
        "phone": "555-555",
        "status": "active",
    },
    {
        "_id": "58aabc92e846502357fc0f69",
        "email": "mail@me.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "office": "1122",
        "phone": "555-555",
    },
    {
        "_id": "58aabc92e846502357fc0f69",
        "email": "mail@me.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "office": "1122",
        "phone": "555-555",
    }
]
```

Comment: `@/name;` extracts all the names, but how can I count them?

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(@/name;)` counts all occurrences of name in the JSON stream.
How do I only count active members? Eg. where status = 'active'

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

COUNT(@/name[status='active'];)